# React Native giving a Component Exception error when trying to use Victory chart component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx, victory-charts

So I am trying to use the Victory library for react native in order to draw a line chart for my budgeting app. Here Is the code I have in my Graph component

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { VictoryLine } from 'victory';

export default function Graph() {
    return (
        <View>
            <VictoryLine />
        </View>
        
        
    )
}
```

Here is the code for where the component is being imported to

```
import React from 'react'
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TextInput } from 'react-native'
import Graph from './Line'

export default function MonthSummary() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.title}>My Summary</Text>
            <Text style={styles.subtitle}>£1,325</Text>
            <Graph />
        </View>
    )

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        width: 350,
        height: 200,
        padding: 20,
        shadowColor: "#000",
        shadowOffset: {
            width: 0,
            height: 2,
        },
        shadowOpacity: 0.25,
        shadowRadius: 3.84,
        elevation: 5,
    },
    title: {
        textTransform: 'uppercase',
        fontSize: 14,
        fontWeight: '600',
        color: '#333333',
    },
    subtitle: {
        color: '#333333',
        fontSize: 30,
        marginTop: 5,
    }
  });
```

But when I run my application I get a Component Exception error. [Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUAwy.png). If anyone could help that would be amazing as I've been struggling with it for hours!

Comment: Unless you are referring to a totally different library, the import should be from "victory-native", maybe you accidentally installed the web library. Also, where do you pass the data prop?

Comment: Il try uninstalling the library and checking its the correct one for react native, but the data is apparently populated with fall backdate if a data prop isn't passed so was just doing that to test it

Comment: Ah, good to know they have dummy data. This should be it, your error message suggests component names with capital letters, this sounds like you have web components in use, because they often times start with lowercase letters like ```<button>``` etc.

Comment: Yep just checked an I installed the web version! Thanks for the help :)

Comment: For sake of completion I will add an answer as others might have this problem as well. I'd appreciate if you mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are using the web library instead of the react native one. Follow [this](https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/docs/native/) to set it up and change your graph component to look like this

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { VictoryLine } from 'victory-native';

export default function Graph() {
    return (
        <View>
            <VictoryLine />
        </View>
        
        
    )
}
```